# SQL Query to find the value which has max number of occurrences in a table without nesting

Tags: sql, nested, max, find-occurrences

I'm working on the following schema (bold text stands for pk, and ":" stand for referenced tables) :

USERS(**username**, name, surname);

PRODUCTS(**id**, name, quantity);

PURCHASES(**user:USERS, product:PRODUCTS, dateAndTime**, quantityPurchased);

**I want to find name and surname of the user who has made the max number of purchases.**

Firstly I use a nested query to find out the number of purchases for each user and then I select the user which purchased >= ALL those values:

```
SELECT name, surname, username
FROM users JOIN purchases ON username = user
GROUP BY name, surname, username
HAVING count(*) >= ALL(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM utenti JOIN acquisti ON username = user
    GROUP BY username)
```

**Is there another way to achieve the same without using nested queries?**

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.  This sounds like a homework assignment, but you seem to have put some work into it.  The idea is to order by the `count(*)` and take the first row.  The syntax in SQL Server, Sybase, and Access is:

```
SELECT top 1 name, surname, username
FROM users as u INNER JOIN
     purchases as p
     ON u.username = p.user
GROUP BY name, surname, username
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

Other databases would put a `limit 1` clause after the `order by`, instead of `top 1`.  And others may have even more arcane syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it was just an exercise i took from an old test of my DB class as "training". I was just curious about other ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the user with most purchased items.

```
SELECT TOP 1
   U.name, U.surname, SUM(P.quantityPurchased) Purchases
FROM users U
  JOIN purchases P
    on U.username= P.user
GROUP BY U.username, U.name, U.surname
ORDER BY Purchases DESC
```

and this will return the user with most purchaes.

```
SELECT TOP 1
   U.name, U.surname, COUNT(*) occurrences
FROM users U
  JOIN purchases P
    on U.username= P.user
GROUP BY U.username, U.name, U.surname
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```